# Efficiently copy large timeseries results in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, time-series, java-stream, influxdb

I am querying data from a timeseries database (Influx in my case) using Java.
I have approximately 20.000-100.000 values (Strings) in the database.
Mapping the results that I get via the Influx Java API to my Domain Objects seems to be very inefficient (ca.0,5s on a small machine). 
I suppose this is due to "resource intensive" object creation of the domain objects.

I am currently using StreamsAPI:

```java
QueryResult series = result.getResults().get(0).getSeries().get(0);

List<ItemHistoryEntity> mappedList = series.getValues().stream().parallel().map(valueList ->
                new ItemHistoryEntity(valueList)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Unfortunately, I downsampling my data at the database is not an option in my case.
How can I do this more efficiently in Java?

EDIT:
Next thing I will do with the list is downsampling. The problem is that for further downsampling, I need the oldest timestamp in the list. To get this timestamp, I need to iterate the full list. Would it be more efficient, to never call `Collectors.toList()` until I have reduced the size of the list, even though I need to iterate it at least twice. Or should I find the oldest timestamp using an additional db query and then iterate the list only once and call the Collector only for the reduce list?

Comment: Hey! It depends on what you want to do with the list. Obviously to have a list of so many objects in RAM is not a good idea. Most likely you should just fetch the stuff on-demand. But feel free to clarify your question by saying what you need the list for.

Comment: Have you tried using a for loop instead of streams API? It adds overhead that can be significant. On the other hand 500ms to process 50000 objects doesn't sound too bad - is there really a problem?

Comment: I think streams is not the problem. As you said, maybe the 500ms is not that bad and the only thing I can do is to find a solution to retrieve less results from the database. I was hoping for a more efficient way to create many similar objects but I think there is no solution to this in Java.